# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex

I'm getting an error on a class I've written

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Class.Salestreegetcontacts.execute: line 67, column 1"

I'm trying to send an auth key save on User, can anyone tell me where I'm messing up?

```
global class  Salestreegetcontacts implements schedulable{
global User STUser{get;set;}
public Id STUserId{get;set;}
 public string cstUsername {get;set;}
 public string cstPassword {get;set;}
 public string cstNode {get;set;}
 public string ClientAcctId {get;set;}
 public string xAuthToken{get;set;}
 public url st_Today{get;set;}
 public url st_Vault{get;set;}
 public string kind {get;set;}
 public string title {get;set;}
 public string description{get;set;}
 public date startdate{get;set;}
 public datetime startdatetime{get;set;}
 public url self{get;set;}
 public Contact__c contact;
 public map<string, string> eventmap;  
 public map<string, string> UserMap;   
 public map<string, string> contactmap;


global User getUserData(){

    If (STUser == null){
    User STUser = [select Id, X_Auth_token__c, CSTlastupdate__c, CST_Node__c, Client_Account_Id__c from User where X_Auth_token__c != null ];
    }
    return STUser;
    }
    global void Userdatamap(){
    if(STUser.X_Auth_Token__c != null){
map<string, string> Usermap = new map<string, string> ();
Usermap.put('Id', string.valueof(STUser.Id));
Usermap.put('xAuth', STUser.X_Auth_token__c);
Usermap.put('LastUpdate', string.valueof(STUser.CSTlastupdate__c));
Usermap.put('Node', STUser.CST_Node__c);
Usermap.put('Client_Account', STUser.Client_Account_Id__c);
}

}
public string xAuth(){
    if(xAuthToken != null){


    xAuthToken = STUser.X_Auth_token__c;
    cstNode = STUser.CST_Node__c;
    ClientAcctId = STUser.Client_Account_Id__c;
    STUserId = STUser.Id;
    }
    return xAuthToken;
    return cstNode;
    return ClientAcctId;
    return STUserId;
}


 global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        map<string, string> eventmap = new map<string, string>();


    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res1 = new HttpResponse();
    Http http1 = new Http();

    req1.setMethod('POST' ); // Method Type
    req1.setEndpoint('https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/node');
    req1.setheader('X-auth-token: ' , Usermap.get('xAuth'));
    string bodyrequest = '';
    Date Todaysdate = Date.today();
    String sMonth = String.valueof(Todaysdate.month());
    String sDay = String.valueof(Todaysdate.day());
    if(sMonth.length()==1){
        sMonth = '0' + sMonth;
        }
    if(sDay.length()==1){
      sDay = '0' + sDay;
      }
      String sToday = String.valueof(Todaysdate.year()) + sMonth + sDay ;
    bodyrequest += '/' + cstNode;
    bodyrequest += '/calendar?from=' + sToday;
    bodyrequest += '&to=' + sToday;

    req1.setbody(bodyrequest);


        res1 = http1.send(req1);
        if(res1.getBody() != null){
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One thing is that `map<string, string> Usermap = new map<string, string> ();` is assigning to a local variable rather than the field of the class. Removing that type at the start `map<string, string>` will avoid that.

Comment: There are 4 returns in a method `return xAuthToken;
    return cstNode;
    return ClientAcctId;
    return STUserId;` Which one you get?

Answer (score 1):

In this block here:

```
if(STUser.X_Auth_Token__c != null){
  map<string, string> Usermap = new map<string, string> ();
  Usermap.put('Id', string.valueof(STUser.Id));
  Usermap.put('xAuth', STUser.X_Auth_token__c);
  Usermap.put('LastUpdate', string.valueof(STUser.CSTlastupdate__c));
  Usermap.put('Node', STUser.CST_Node__c);
  Usermap.put('Client_Account', STUser.Client_Account_Id__c);
}
```

you are conditionally setting the map when STUser.X_Auth_Token__c is not null. However, you are accessing the map without condition on line 67. To prevent the dreaded "NullPointerException", you can first check if the map contains the key.
`if (Usermap.containsKey('xAuth'))`... or use the same check you had above `if(STUser.X_Auth_Token__c != null){`

Answer (score 0):

Try initiating `User STUser = new User();` before using it. It might help.